# Executing command line, cd doesn't work

Tags: android, command-line, terminal

I'm trying to execute `cd` using

```
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = stream.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append('\n');
        }
        stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
        while ((line = stream.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

`ls` works. But `cd dir` doesn't work. It doesn't change the directory. If I execute `pwd`, it still shows `/`. I read that each time `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);` is executed, it creates a new shell. I think I need to capture that shell some how and maintain it till the user closes the app.

Not just that, I'm not getting any errors in my output. Eg. when I put a command that does not exist, I don't get the error message.

Comment: You haven't described what "doesn't work" means here. Does it throw an exception? Since the `cd` command doesn't output anything on success (unlike `ls`), how do you know it has failed? Also - what directory are you attempting to change to? Android has a lot of restrictions on what directories Apps are allowed to access.

Comment: I've updated the answer. It also doesn't give me any error if I try to `cd` to a directory that doesn't exist. Any idea why I'm not getting the error message?

Answer (score 1):

> I read that each time Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); is executed,
>   it creates a new shell.

That is correct. When you call `Runtime.exec()` for each command, you are creating a new process. Each process gets its own environment, including a separate working directory which does not affect the parent process (your app), or any other processes you create afterwards.

> I'm not getting any errors in my output

You don't get any errors because the shell commands do not fail to execute. The commands simply return a status code indicating success or failure when the process terminates - the code can be obtained via `Process.exitValue()` - but make sure the process has finished first using `Process.waitFor()`.

If you want to execute multiple commands, you could use `exec()` to launch a shell executable and then write commands and read replies via the input and output streams, or just join all the commands together using semicolons and execute them directly using a command line like:

`sh -c 'cd /;pwd'`